# Function with return value uses AlertDialog

Tags: android, asynchronous

I'm overriding a function from an interface (which I can't modify), let's say

```
public abstract int getResult();
```

In this function, I'd like to ask the user of what the result should be, using an AlertDialog. So my implementation should be something like:

```
public int getResult() {
    int result;

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                result = 1;
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                result = 2;
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("What is the result?").setPositiveButton("1", dialogClickListener)
        .setNegativeButton("2", dialogClickListener).show();

    return result;
}
```

Obviously, this won't work due to the asynchronous nature of the AlertDialog. What is the proper way to deal with this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

you must run this code only on UI Thread like:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getResult();
        }
    });
```

or

```
    public int getResult(){
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // your code
        }
    });
 }
```